# Pointer to pointer of struct

Tags: c

I'm a bit confused about this subject. Let's say I have this struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char a;
    int num;
} 
t_per;
```

and I want to sort a `t_per* data` by `num`. Then I would do something like:

```
void sort(t_per* data)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    t_per aux;
    for(i = 0; data[i].num != 0; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; data[j].num != 0; j++)
        {
            if(data[i].num > data[j].num)
            {
                aux = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But what if I have a `t_per** data`? Would this be correct?

```
void sort(t_per** data)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    t_per aux;
    for(i = 0; (*data[i]).num != 0; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; (*data[j]).num != 0; j++)
        {
            if((*data[i]).num > (*data[j]).num)
            {
                aux = *data[i];
                *data[i] = *data[j];
                *data[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edited for legibility.

Comment: Remember that for any pointer or array `data` and index `i`, the expression `*(data + i)` is *exactly* equal to `data[i]`. The latter, `data[i]`, is usually easier to read and understand, and is a couple of characters less to write.

Comment: As for your problem, how do you *call* your `sort` function? With *what*? Please try to create an [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Note that `*data[i]` is equal to `*(data[i])`, not the very different `(*data)[i]`. Which one is correct? We don't really know without that [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly writing `data` as an array of pointers may help. I am not sure of your purpose to use `t_per**` and generally it is adopted to reduce the cost of copying the `t_per` structures. This kind of sorting would manipulate on an array that stores pointers to the structures and it swaps the pointers in the array rather than `t_per` themselves. It should be just the same as `void sort(T_PER[] data)` in languages like java where objects are themselves pointers.

```
void sort(t_per* data[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    t_per* aux;
    for(i = 0; data[i]->num != 0; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; data[j]->num != 0; j++)
        {
            if (data[i]->num > data[j]->num)
            {
                aux = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if you decided to write or swap directly on `t_per` objects, your code would work. In any case, you should make sure that `data` is an array which stores `t_per*`.